Electricity to 2nd pole barn
I have a 100 amp sub panel installed in a 24x32 pole barn from my cabin.  A larger pole barn (32x48) was recently built about 100 feet away.  Can I extend wiring underground from the pole barn with the sub panel to the larger one?  Or do I need a second subpanel for the larger barn too? In any respect, would I run 6-gauge wire to the newer barn?  The larger barn will have lights and two garage openers.  I do not plan using machinery that would require alot of amps.

Size of lights might be important.  Lights to most people are a few watts, but a few 1000w or bigger size is possible in a barn.

If you are kneejerking to 6 gauge copper, stop. 4 or even 2 gauge aluminum is a lot more cost efficient. Sometimes the 2 is less expensive than the 4. What is the present feed to the first barn, and what loads does it have? Better yet, what is its load calculation?

Yes, daisy chaining subpanels is fine as long as the feeder can carry the load.  You would never use copper wire for a feeder unless you have a weird conduit fill issue, use #2 aluminum for 90A.

There are four different issues here:
Do you need a subpanel?
YES. Well, technically there may be limited ways to make things work without one. But from a practical standpoint, you need a subpanel in each building, even if there are only a few circuits. You also need:

A disconnect in each building. The easiest way to do that is to use a "main panel" as a subpanel, because the main breaker in that panel, even if it is far larger than the feed to the panel, can be used as a disconnect. The next easiest way is to have the feed go into a backfed double-breaker on a panel that doesn't have a main breaker.
Ground rods in each building. Normally one wire to two rods, several feet apart.
To keep ground and neutral separate in the panel. That means ground wires on ground bar, neutral wires on neutral bar and no bond between neutral and ground/

The subpanel could be a 6 space tiny little thing with 2 spaces for a backfed double breaker, 1 space for each each garage opener, 1 space for lights and 1 space for convenience receptacles. Or it could be a 30 or even 40 space full size main panel. The choice is yours. Might just depend on what is on sale that day at a big box store.
Topology
The electrons don't care much which direction they go. So Main->A->B is fine. And so is Main->A and Main->B. There is some voltage drop concern with the 2 x 100 feet combined together, but practically speaking that should not be an issue since you are not running large loads. So whatever is easiest to trench.
Load Calculation
You need to make sure each panel has all the power it needs. The main panel/utility service has to supply everything in all the panels. The feed from the main panel to subpanel A needs to supply everything in A and if B is connected to A then it needs to handle that as well. Subpanel B just needs to worry about itself.
The way to to do this is a Load Calculation, which takes into account fixed equipment, HVAC, water heating (if electric), cooking equipment, required circuits (kitchen, bathroom, etc. in the house - doesn't really apply to the barns) and a general factor based on the size of the building. It is not "guess" (you'll be way high or low), it is not "add the breaker handle values" (you'll be way high), it is not "electric bill peak demand" (that doesn't account for changes in use, seasonal issues, etc.)
Wire Size
Once you have the Load Calculation for the new subpanel, now you can determine how much you need to feed it, which will determine the wire size. Check an ampacity chart for the details. "6 AWG" is meaningless - depending on the type of wire (copper or aluminum, wires vs. cable, etc.) it could handle anywhere from 50A to 65A. Buying it a bit large is OK, as it lets you expand in the future.
Also consider wires in conduit instead of cable. More work upfront but potential savings in the future if you need to upgrade. Plus the trench may not need to be as deep.
